# Selecting all related rows with BigQuery (reading logs from GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

My Google App Engine logs are being exported to BigQuery via the standard [streaming export tool](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#log_entries_in_google_bigquery). I'd like to query "show me all log lines for requests in which any log line contains a string".

This query gives me the request ids I'm interested in:

```
SELECT protoPayload.requestId AS reqId
  FROM TABLE_QUERY(logs, 'true') 
  WHERE protoPayload.line.logMessage contains 'INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR'
```

...and this lets me query for the related lines:

```
SELECT
  metadata.timestamp AS Time,
  protoPayload.host AS Host,
  protoPayload.status AS Status,
  protoPayload.resource AS Path,
  protoPayload.line.logMessage
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY(logs, 'true')
WHERE
  protoPayload.requestId in ("requestid1", "requestid2", "etc")
ORDER BY time
```

However, I'm having trouble combining the two into a single query. BQ doesn't seem to allow subselects in the WHERE clause and I get confusing error messages when I try to do a traditional self-join with named tables. What's the secret?

Comment: Joining should work. What's the confusing error message? Can you share your join sql so we can help edit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select lines where at least one of logMessage contains given string, you can use OMIT IF construct

```
SELECT
  metadata.timestamp AS Time,
  protoPayload.host AS Host,
  protoPayload.status AS Status,
  protoPayload.resource AS Path,
  protoPayload.line.logMessage
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY(logs, 'true')
OMIT RECORD IF
  EVERY(NOT (protoPayload.line.logMessage contains 'INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR'))
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: No, that returns only the specific lines that match. protoPayload.line is a repeated record field; I want all the lines from a request given that any one of the lines in the request match the condition.

Comment: Got it - I changed the proposed answer accordingly

Comment: Wow, it's not what I expected at all. Works great - thanks!